# How to hold the control till animation is done in cocos2dx 3.0

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want my code should not execute the next line of code till the animation is running.
just like this 
(void)animateNewCookies:(NSArray *)columns completion:(dispatch_block_t)completion 
now in above code it wont execute the next line until this AnimatenewCookies method is done with its execution. but the above code is of objective c for ios platform and i want to achive the same in C++ for cocos2dx 3.0 with Visual studio 2013.
here is my code :

```
MoveTo * moveCandyA = MoveTo::create(Duration, swap->candyB->getCandySprite()->getPosition());
    swap->candyA->getCandySprite()->runAction(Repeat::create(moveCandyA, 1));

    MoveTo * moveCandyB = MoveTo::create(Duration, swap->candyA->getCandySprite()->getPosition());

swap->candyB->getCandySprite()->runAction(Repeat::create(moveCandyB, 1));
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

```
runAction(Repeat::create(Sequence::create(moveCandyA,firstDelay,moveCandyB,secondDelay,NULL),5));
```

Comment: i have already tried this , its not working. It calls the callFunc but it wont wait for this action to get completed , and immediately executes the next instruction.that is again a action so before completion of my first move animation it start the second one. And if there is any other point you want to tell please elaborate.. Thanks for your reply..

Comment: Can you show how do you exactly call your second animation with CallFunc?

Comment: swap->candyA->getCandySprite()->runAction(Sequence::create(moveCandyA, 
  CallFunc::create(std::bind(&CandyScene::actionCallBackFuncToHoldTheProcess, this, swap, moveCandyA)), NULL));

Comment: void CandyScene::actionCallBackFuncToHoldTheProcess(CandySwap *swap, MoveTo* action){
 const float Duration = 0.2;
 MoveTo * moveCandyB = MoveTo::create(Duration, swap->candyA->getCandySprite()->getPosition());
 swap->candyB->getCandySprite()->runAction(Sequence::create(moveCandyB, action, NULL));
}

Comment: but this is not working i guess i am doing it wrong please correct me ..Thanks for your reply !!!!

Comment: And if there is any alternative way please suggest me that ,cos i have to play the animation in loop so call func does not seems to be a good way to do this.